# How to denote .abc = .xyz in CSS (not comma-separated)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap 2.3.1, there is a portion:

```
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  outline: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}
```

I want to use Bootstrap in WordPress. In WordPress, instead of `.active`, there is a class named `.current-menu-item`. So if I don't want to touch the bootstrap CSS, and so then in my custom stylesheet, if I want to repeat the same code with a slight difference, like:

```
.dropdown-menu > .current-menu-item > a { bla bla bla }
```

### NEW THOUGHT ?

- Is there a new way to denote those classes, something simply like `.a` = `.b`?

With my example:

```
.dropdown-menu > .active > a = .dropdown-menu > .current-menu-item > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover = .dropdown-menu > .current-menu-item > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus = .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus { bla bla bla }
```

I know it can be done, simply by comma-seperated classes, but in that way the statements are to be mentioned again. I don't want such huge code block's repeat.

Comment: Not as far as I know. However, with languages like LESS (which is what bootstrap is written in), one can do this, so it probably will be easier to recompile bootstrap with your changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS has no native way to do this.  If you want to "copy" styles from one selector to another, you need a CSS preprocessor.

```
.foo {
    background: blue;
}
```

Sass:

```
.bar {
    @extend .foo;
}
```

LESS:

```
.bar {
    .foo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). Here you can create variables, and do something like this:

```
@color: #4D926F;

.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .current-menu-item > a {@color;}
```